# Iterating through JSON using Ruby

Tags: ruby, json, parsing

I am trying to iterate through the JSON below but I am getting the error

```
./test.rb:39:in `[]': can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)
    from ./test.rb:39:in `block in <main>'
    from ./test.rb:38:in `each'
    from ./test.rb:38:in `<main>'
```

From this code (line 39=print child['data']['body'])

Can anyone show me what i am doing wrong?

```
data = JSON.parse(res.body)

38 data.each do |child|
39    print child['data']['body']
40 end
```

Here is what res.body is:

```
{ "views": [ "Logs_Messages","Content_Sources","Bitrates_HD_Encoder","Hardware_Status_eCMM","Bitrates_Per_Program","Content_OOB_SI","Debug_Dump","Hardware_Status_In_Band_Tuners","Alarms_Current","Version_Information","Software_Status_License","Hardware_Status_Module_Presence","Reboot","Content_Mappings","Logs_Persistent","Content_Routing","Software_Status_Transcoder_Enabled","Software_Status_Code_Download","Decryption_Identification","Hardware_Status_System_Monitoring","Software_Status_Operating_System_Stats","Software_Status_TLV","Hardware_Status_Out_of_Band_Tuner","Content_EPG","Hardware_Status_HD_Encoders","Alarms_History","Bitrates_Output","Decryption_Status","Bitrates_Input","Software_Status_EPG_Download","Interfaces","Hardware_Status_Output_Module"] }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example `data` on line 38 should be the contents of `res.body`.

If we look at the hash that you say `res.body` is, we can see that it is a hash with one key, "views", and that key points to an array of values.

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with your script so far. I will take a guess that you are currently trying to print out each of the items in the array. To do that, you would need to do the following:

```
data = JSON.parse(res.body)

data["views"].each do |view|
  print view
end
```

This accesses the value stored at the key `views` in `data`, the array, and then loops over the values in that array, printing them out as it goes.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: I don't think using the symbol `:views` as the key will work, as the default JSON parser will return a hash with string keys. `"views"` would be the key to use in that case.

Comment: Wow thanks for the quick response ... I get a different error ./test.rb:41:in `<main>': undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Comment: Argh, you're right, thanks @joonty. The text actually parsed as a ruby array without JSON parsing when I tried that in irb. I've updated now.

Comment: @robm I've just updated my answer after joonty pointed out a mistake. Try with the key `"views"` not the key `:views`.

Comment: @robm There should be the outline of a check mark under the voting arrows to the left of the question. Clicking that will mark it as the answer. :)